# Blank screen displayed when clicked on the datepicker v 4.2.11 for Android 12 in react native

Tags: react-native, datepicker

Blank screen displayed when clicked on the datepicker v 4.2.11 for Android 12 in react native

i want a permanent solution for Blank screen displayed when clicked on the datepicker v 4.2.11 for Android 12 in react native?